# SQL joins and inner joins and is null

Tags: sql-server, join, inner-join

[DB schema diagram here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMv8J.png)

I'm trying to return a list of coupons not associated with store id 1 I'm trying to return coupon 1

Here's my effort

```
Select c.id
from Coupon c
left join signups s on s.couponid = c.id
inner join storelist sl on sl.groupid = s.groupid
where sl,id = 1 and s.couponid is null
```

Thanks

Comment: I think I already tried left join left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are going to return columns from the signups and storelist tables, I would approach your problem like this; simply selecting from the coupon table and using `NOT IN` to filter out the specified store.

```
SELECT c.id
FROM coupon c
WHERE c.id NOT IN (
    SELECT s.couponid 
    FROM signups s
        JOIN storelist sl ON s.groupid = sl.groupid
    WHERE sl.id = 1
)
```

Comment: This worked thanks, is it possible to avoid the inner query?

Comment: You may be able to change it to a `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, or `FULL` join depending on your needs, but you will need some kind of join since your ids are spread across different tables. Is there a reason you are trying to avoid it?

Comment: Just efficiency

Answer (score 0):

Just use "not equal" in the where clause:

```
select c.id
from Coupon c
inner join signups s on s.couponid = c.id
inner join storelist sl on sl.groupid = s.groupid
where sl.id <> 1
```

---

### EDIT 2

[image]

So, the "expected result" (from that data) when using the query above is "no result". However if you correct the data so that signups can only refer to existing stores, then you would see store 2 listed when you use `where sl.id <> 1`

---

### EDIT 1

Data taken from data model image

[image]

> ```
> CREATE TABLE StoreList
>     ([id] int, [groupid] int, [address] varchar(50))
> ;
>    
> INSERT INTO StoreList
>     ([id], [groupid], [address])
> VALUES
>     (1, 3, '35 Sharkey Rd'),
>     (2, 4, '56 Jim Road')
> ;
>
>
> CREATE TABLE signups
>     ([id] int, [groupid] int, [couponid] int)
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO signups
>     ([id], [groupid], [couponid])
> VALUES
>     (1, 1, 2),
>     (2, 3, 2)
> ;
>
>
> CREATE TABLE Coupon
>     ([id] int, [name] varchar(8))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO Coupon
>     ([id], [name])
> VALUES
>     (1, 'coupon 1'),
>     (2, 'coupon 2')
> ;
>
> select sl.id as sl_id, *
> from Coupon c
> inner join signups s on s.couponid = c.id
> inner join storelist sl on sl.groupid = s.groupid
>
> ;
>
> select sl.id as sl_id, *
> from Coupon c
> inner join signups s on s.couponid = c.id
> inner join storelist sl on sl.groupid = s.groupid
> where sl.id <> 1
> ;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> sl_id | id | name     | id | groupid | couponid | id | groupid | address      
> ----: | -: | :------- | -: | ------: | -------: | -: | ------: | :------------
>     1 |  2 | coupon 2 |  2 |       3 |        2 |  1 |       3 | 35 Sharkey Rd
>
> sl_id | id | name | id | groupid | couponid | id | groupid | address
> ----: | -: | :--- | -: | ------: | -------: | -: | ------: | :------
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5c09aaec8e772d85d07bc7c2f2fff83f)*

As you can see from the above proof, if sl.id is not equal to 1 then indeed no stores with an id of one will be returned.

Comment: I was hoping for an efficient solution like this but it didn't work for me, it returned a long list of 2's and 1's in the real data

Comment: How can the column sl.id be 1 if the where says sl.id not equal 1?  Sorry but the result you refer to does not make sense. Are you sure you output the sl.id ?

Comment: by the way, the data given on the image for table signups does not refer to store number 2, that is why only 1 coupon gets displayed in the query with no where clause. Always examine the sample data.

Comment: My goal is to output the Coupons that are not associated with that store (sl).  I would want the query to return coupon id 1

Comment: Sigh. Yes. If course it is. But the only data i have refers to store1 or a store that does not exist. The first result has no where clause. The second result does have a where clause. (The data is example in your image is bad). So when the where clause is applied there are no results. Which is the correct answer IF YOU UNDERSTAND THE DATA.  The not equals 1 in the where clause is all you need.

Comment: Another images and explanation added to help (I hope).

Comment: Instead of returning no rows, can you return coupon 1?

Comment: Can i return coupon 1? With the data from your iriginal image?  Lets see. Coupon 1 has coupinid = 1. In the signups tabke both rows refer to coupinid =2. So **coupon 1 is NOT REFERENCED IN THE SIGNUPS TABLE**.  Please explain how this will help my answer be chosen as accepted.

Comment: Exactly I want to select the coupons that are not in signups

Comment: Good grief! Seems I went right down the wrong rabbit hole. Have a look at my second answer now (which is utterly different to where I was heading originally). Hopefully that answer is what you were seeking.

Answer (score 0):

To discover coupons not referenced at all in the signups table then one simple option is to use a "left excluding join":

```
select c.*
from coupons c
left join signups s on c.couponid = s.couponid
where s.couponid IS NULL
```

Here you perform a join when a coupon is referenced in signups, but then exclude those matched rows via the where clause leaving you with only the unmatched rows.

Another option is a "semi-join" via NOT EXISTS:

```
select c.*
from coupons c
where NOT EXISTS (
     select NULL
     from signups s
     where c.couponid = s.couponid
     )
```

Note that the select clause in that subquery is not evaluated, it exists really because syntax rules require any select query to commence with the select keyword. It is the from and where clauses that provide the information needed to test EXISTS or NOT EXISTS, hence any of these "select NULL", "select 1" or "select *" may be used, it is simply a matter of preference which one you do use.